# javaFX translate animation doesn't trigger in both directions?

Tags: java, animation, events, javafx, onclick

Right now I'm trying to code a simple abacus with JavaFX. There are balls on horizontal rails arranged in a gridpane, and I'm using a translateTransition to move them to the right on click. The following is the code I have right now, which works fine on any of the balls in the grid except it only animates the movement to the right. On the second click, the ball jumps back to the left to its original position without the animation and I can't figure out why it's not animating. Any help or ideas would be greatly appreciated!

```
private void onClick(final Circle circle) {
    circle.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
        public void handle(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
            //set movement direction, check if circle has been moved
            int targetX = 200;
            if (circle.getTranslateX() > 1) {
                targetX = 0;
            }   

            //animation trigger and details
            TranslateTransition push = new TranslateTransition(Duration.millis(500));
            push.setNode(circle);
            push.setFromX(circle.getCenterX());
            push.setToX(targetX);
            push.play();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: You're creating a new animation every time the button is clicked. Furthermore during this animation `centerX` is never modified. `translateX` is morified. You always start from the same initial value for `translateX` during the animation which most likely does not match the current value of the `translateX` property...

Comment: Ah yeah turns out all I had to do was change it so it takes push.setFromX(circle.getTranslateX()) and now it works like a charm. Thanks!